# copying field custom from purchase order line to stock move in odoo

Tags: odoo, stock, odoo-13

I am using odoo 13. I have a custom field weight in Purchase order line.
I want to copying the value of this field to custom field in stock move.
I know that to transfer the value of the field from sale order to stock move I can do it in the following way.

```
class StockMoveLine(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.move'

    weight = fields.Float(
        compute='_compute_weight' )
    

    def _compute_weight(self):

        for move in self:
            if not (move.picking_id and move.picking_id.group_id):
                continue
            picking = move.picking_id
            sale_order = self.env['sale.order'].sudo().search([
                ('procurement_group_id', '=', picking.group_id.id)], limit=1)
            # print(picking)
            
            if sale_order:
                for line in sale_order.order_line:
                    if line.product_id.id != move.product_id.id:
                        continue
                    move.update({
                        'weight': line.weight,
                    })
                continue
            else:
                # move.update({
                #         'weight': move.weight,
                # })
```

However I find myself stuck in the else to pass the field from purchase to stock move

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `purchase_line_id` field on `stock.move` which is link to `purchase.order.line`

Code - [PoL Reference in Stock Move](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/purchase_stock/models/stock.py#L18)

Answer (score 0):

If you're inheriting ***stock.move***, then change your model name to `class StockMove(models.Model):` instead of `class StockMoveLine(models.Model):`.

Try using ***@api.depends*** on your compute function.